# Multiple CSVs, one structure -> multiple tables with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have multiple CSVs - one file for one exam and in each file results of this exam for country's regions. The structure is the same :

- region
- averageresult
- region_code

And I want to process all of the files at once.

I have managed to use forloop container, use 2 variables - for the folder and for the filename and funnel it all into one table. However, that is not satisfactory as it becomes incomprehensive.

My only guess is that I am stuck at setting up OLEDB/SQLServer Destination. In this step I need to set up a new table. And I don't know what to do in order to produce these tables over and over again for each consecutive file - as the structure is the same.

Alternatively - Is there a way for SSIS to funnel all files into one table but somehow mark filenames, divide it or something, so I know which file this number came from?